# show multiple tables data in a single view from multiple models in a single model class

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to get data from more than one table in a single view and and show it in different dividers but how i do i can not know about this please give me reply.

```
@using _5Oppertunities.org.Models
@model ViewmodelForJobandEducation
<div>
<table class="table table-responsive table-striped  table-hover">
                                        <thead class="thead-inverse">
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>#</th>
                                                <th class="degtd">ja</th>
                                                <th>Title</th>
                                                <th>year</th>
                                                <th class="tdinst">Institution</th>
                                                <th></th>
                                                <th></th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th scope="row">1</th>
                                                <td class="degtd">Mark</td>
                                                <td>Otto</td>
                                                <td>mdo</td>
                                                <td class="tdinst">mdo</td>
                                                <td class="tdsp"><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
                                                <td class="tdsp"><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th scope="row">2</th>
                                                <td class="degtd">Jacob</td>
                                                <td>Thornton</td>
                                                <td>fat</td>
                                                <td class="tdinst">mdo</td>
                                                <td class="tdsp"><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
                                                <td class="tdsp"><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th scope="row">3</th>
                                                <td class="degtd">Larry</td>
                                                <td>the Bird</td>
                                                <td>twitter</td>
                                                <td class="tdinst">mdo</td>
                                                <td class="tdsp"><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
                                                <td class="tdsp"><a href="#"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></a></td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>
</div>
```

i want to show here and i use this class for view data

```
public class ViewmodelForJobandEducation
    {
        public IEnumerable<CandidateInformation> CandidateInformation { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<EducationInformation> EducationInformaation { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<JobHistory> JobHistroy { get; set; }
    }
```

i fetch data from this class and show data.

Answer (score 0):

Use @foreach loop in your cshtml page and retrive all your Ienumerable List throught it.